# Sacrificing performance for ease of development and portability worth it for mobile platforms?

Tags: android, ios

So I have been working on a medium sized enterprise app for the iPhone that I may have to port to Android. I wrote the app using the native iOS SDK without any care for portability. I initially cringed at having to re-write the entire app in Java and maintaining two code bases, so I looked into some of the cross platform options.

I wrote a simple "hello world" in two cross platform applications and one using the native SDK just to get a feel for the performance and stability of each platform. This was by no means a completely exhaustive experiment, just quick and dirty test. I was surprised to find that PhoneGap and Appcelerator’s Titanium had a very noticeable startup time just to display "hello world". Additionally, both PhoneGap and Titanium crashed if I closed the application and then reopened it in rapid succession (30-40 rapid iterations). The Native app on the other had never had any problems.

Initially I thought I could live with the slower startup times because of the promise of one code base to rule them all. Then I ran into the following potential roadblocks:

1. Debugging support seems limited.

   According to the phone gap [wiki](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/16494768/Debugging%20PhoneGap%20Apps) it is recommended that you debug (1) on your desktop (2) using a   remote web inspector (3) printf debugging [are you kidding?] or (4) using [weinre](http://debug.phonegap.com/)

   Debugging for Titanium is slightly better but still lacks on device debugging support. There is an open [request](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-501?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) for on device debugging that is a year old so it may get fixed in the future.

   Debugging may not be a problem on small projects with a few developers but it quickly becomes very important the larger the project gets and as more developers work on the same code base.
2. You still have to adjust the UI for each device.

   This may or may not be a concern for some people but I would like our app to look like a native app and follow each platform's human interface guidelines. So I will still have duplicate code at the UI layer.

At this point given the fact that I have to have separate UI code for each device and the on-device debugging options are not as rich as a native app I don't see the savings that a cross platform development framework will give. I am thinking that the best route to go is to re-write my models in C and then I can share that code between Android (using the NDK) and iOS with each device having is own native UI.

So my question is, what experiences with cross platform mobile frameworks does anyone have? Are my fears of limited debugging and duplicated UI code unfounded? Please keep in mind I want to have an application that looks like a native app for each platform.

For those of you that have used a cross platform framework how large was the project? What problems did you run into? Would you use the framework again?

-Shane

Comment: This is not a suitable question for StackOverflow. Please read [this  FAQ entry](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask). This would have been better as 4 separate SO questions (1. asking for other alternatives for PhoneGap debugging, 2. same question for Titanium Mobile, 3. asking if there is an HTML/CSS/JS technique for getting Web apps to look native on Android, 4. same question for iOS), each tagged for the appropriate audience. "What problems..." and "Would you use the framework again" are the sorts of open-ended questions that SO is not targeting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will break up the question to make it more targeted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used appcelerators titanium quite a bit. My general feeling is that the IOS section is very good but the android is still lacking, particularly in error messages, debugging isn't so bad as all you have to do is add a few print outs, but the issue being that 99% of the errors on android will be something like app crashed with nullPointerException with no hint as to where because its coming from the underlying java, it can be tricky to say the least.

However I will say the UI stuff is not an issue, titanium takes control of automatically scaling the apps to different device screens (when a setting is turned on - should look into this came in with 1.7). So generally the only issues you will have is device specific things, like having a right nav button in IOS, there is no android equivalent so you have to code something special for that, which is understandable given there 2 different platforms.

I'm not sure what I would do given the IOS is already fully developed, people generally go to this to avoid a learning curve for both platforms and to save time with keeping the same code base, Not sure how much benefit you will get out of this. Appcelerator is good but there are bugs in controls, it will be slower and it will take time to learn but it does have benefits.

I personally wouldn't use phonegap as I don't like the idea of it basically being a webview wrapper and I've had enough browser based issues on desktops to last me a lifetime.